# How do I get a reference to a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am trying to get a reference to a `LinearLayout` so I can add an element.

Here is my xml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/myLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

Is it acceptable to have the line `android:id="@+id/myLayout"` in there?

My incorrect attempt to try and get a reference to my layout is with the following:

```
LayoutInflater myLayoutInflater;
LinearLayout myLayout;

if((myLayoutInflater = m_Context.getLayoutInflater()) != null) {
    myLayout = (LinearLayout) myLayoutInflater.inflate(R.id.myLayout, null);
}
```

It underlines the `R.id.myLayout` in the `inflate()` line in red saying:

`Expected resource of type Layout. Ensure resource ids passed to APIs are of the right type.`

Comment: Layout inflater required layout file id not linearlayout id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ok to find a view by id for a layout just like you do for a view:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
```

This will do the trick if you are in an Activity context.

To add a view to it you can then do:

```
layout.addView(...)
```

You are getting that error because the LayoutInflater expects the **name of the layout file** not your layout id, so something like `R.layout.item_layout`. You also don't want to pass null for the parent view group in most cases so I would not recommend inflating it this way unless you know the parent layout.

Comment: All answers were great, but I chose this as the correct answer as it is the simplest.

Answer (score 2):

There's a misunderstanding about those methods.

- `LayoutInflater.inflate`

This method expects the `id` of a layout file (and not of a layout view). So, you should call:

```
myLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.<NAME_OF_THE_XML_LAYOUT_FILE>, null);
```

That method will return whole view that was inflated. So, now that you have the inflated view, you can search `Views` inside of it. You can search view by their ID.

- `findViewById()`

This method expects the `id` of the `View`. So, here, you should call:

```
View inflatedView = myLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.<NAME_OF_THE_XML_LAYOUT_FILE>, null);
LinearLayout linearLayout = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.myLayout); // Assuming you added android:id="@+id/myLayout" to the LinearLayout
```

Note that first, we inflated the xml file and then, we started to seach for views inside of it.

**HOWEVER**

If your view is part of an Activity, you don't need to inflate that layout. You can instead:

```
public void onCreate() {
    ....
    // This will inflate and add your layout to the actvity
    setContentView(R.layout.<NAME_OF_THE_LAYOUT_FILE);

    // After that line, you can call:
    LinearLayout linearLayout = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.myLayout); // Assuming you added android:id="@+id/myLayout" to the LinearLayout

    // Since your view was added to the activity, you can search for R.id.myLayout
    // If you search for any view before setContentView(), it will return null
    // Because no view was added the screen yet
}
```

Comment: This best explained what I was doing wrong and is the best answer to learn from. However, I chose the other answer as it was simpler and achieved what I wanted. But, thanks for this answer as I really understand things a lot more.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

```
LayoutInflater myLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.fromContext(mContext);
LinearLayout myLayout = myLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_file, null);
View view = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
```